# Adding credentials for tokenprovider in web.config

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, servicebus

Edit: more details:

A little bit more info about my problem:

I use the Service Bus to send asynchronous events to a WCF service. I have a client with this configuration:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="sb://[Server].[Domain]/NameSpace/eventqueue"
    behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior" binding="netMessagingBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="messagingBinding" contract="xxx.IEventQueueService"
    name="Subscriber" />
</client>
```

Note that it's a virtual server in our own domain.

This is the behavior and bindingConfig:

```
<behavior name="securityBehavior">
          <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
            <tokenProvider>
              <windowsAuthentication>
                <stsUris>
                  <stsUri value="https://[Server].[Domain]:9355/[Namespace]" />
                </stsUris>
              </windowsAuthentication>
            </tokenProvider>
          </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        </behavior>

      <netMessagingBinding>
        <binding name="messagingBinding" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00" sessionIdleTimeout="00:01:00" prefetchCount="-1">
          <transportSettings batchFlushInterval="00:00:01" />
        </binding>
      </netMessagingBinding>
```

And my WCF Service is using the same configuration:

```
<services>
  <service name="xxx.EventQueueService">
    <endpoint address="sb://[SERVER].[DOMAIN]/Namespace/eventqueue"
      behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior" binding="netMessagingBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="messagingBinding" name="EventQueueClientService"
      contract="xxx.IEventQueueService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/xxx.ExternalServices/EventQueueService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>

</services>
```

This works great if I run my project on my develop computer. But now, I want to deploy it to the server, the same of my Service Bus. And that fails...

Old Edit:Ok, I found this webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.configuration.windowselement.aspx

but these two options doesn't work:

```
<windowsAuthentication userName="xxx" password="xxx" domain="xxx">

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.SharedSecretTokenProvider.DecodeSecret(String issuerSecret)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Description.SharedSecretCredential.CreateTokenProvider()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Description.TransportClientCredentialBase.get_TokenProvider()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.TransportClientEndpointBehavior.get_TokenProvider()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.NetMessagingTransportBindingElement.CreateMessagingFactorySettings(BindingContext context)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ServiceBusChannelListener`1..ctor(BindingContext context, NetMessagingTransportBindingElement transport)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.NetMessagingTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.MaybeCreateListener(Boolean actuallyCreate, Type[] supportedChannels, Binding binding, BindingParameterCollection parameters, Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, ServiceThrottle throttle, IChannelListener& result, Boolean supportContextSession)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelListener(StuffPerListenUriInfo stuff, ServiceHostBase serviceHost, Uri listenUri, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, Boolean supportContextSession, IChannelListener& result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo info)
```

And

```
<windowsAuthentication>

<userName value="xxx">
```

=> Property "userName" is not a ConfigurationElement

Comment: Which version of the servicebus dll are you using in your web application?

Comment: 1.8.0.0, from NuGet. (Service Bus 1.0 for Windows Server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for this problem.

When deploying your application, make sure that the owner of the IISPool (or the user that is impersonated) is also member of ManagedUsers of the Service Bus Namespace. You can check that with Get-SBNamespace -Name .

Adding user to namespace:Set-SBNamespace -Name  -ManageUsers